# NAnt: How to replace a set of files from other directory

Tags: .net, nant

I need to replace all the files contained in a dir with all the files that exists in other.

This would be a pseudo code for this task:

```
  foreach (string file in /foo/var)
  {
    srcFile = "/other/dir/" + GetFileName(file);
    Copy(srcFile, file);
  }
```

I need to replace the file only if exists in both `/foo/var` and `/other/dir`. Also there are files that exist in `/foo/var` and do not exist in `/other/dir` and vice versa.

What is the best way to do it with NAnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job. It will only look at files in the root target directory and ignore subfolders. It will need a bit more work if you want it to include files in subfolders

```
<project name="Sync" default="sync" xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.85/nant.xsd">

  <property name="source.path" value="D:\test\source\" />
  <property name="target.path" value="D:\test\target\" />

  <target name="sync" description="Copies only the matching files to a folder">
    <foreach item="File" property="targetFile">
      <in>
        <items basedir="${target.path}"> <!-- include all files from the target path -->
          <include name="*" /> <!-- this will not include subfolders -->
        </items>
      </in>
      <do>
        <if test="${file::exists(source.path + path::get-file-name(targetFile))}">
            <copy 
                file="${source.path + path::get-file-name(targetFile)}"
                tofile="${targetFile}"
                overwrite="true"
                 />
        </if>
      </do>
    </foreach>
    </target>
</project>
```

I tested it with Nant 0.86

Answer (score 1):

I think you could pretty much use your pseudocode example. See [the foreach task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/foreach.html) and [the copy task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/copy.html). And [the path manipulation functions](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/index.html#Path).